# What is the difference between "televido" and "televidilo"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Both can be translated to English with *Television*. What is the meaning of both and how they differ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Televidilo* is a television set (usually just a called a TV in English), and *televido* is the general concept (usually used without an article in English).

Here are some examples from *Monato*:

> Ekde la lastjara aŭtuno en la litova nacia televido aperis programo “Malfermu pordon”

Here *televido* refers to the national system of broadcasting television in Lithuania. If it was *televidilo* it would imply Lithuania has a single national TV set that everybody has to take turns watching.

> Se vi ankoraŭ ne kredas, ke la iraka reĝimo ne helpas al Alkaido, malŝaltu la televidilon, forĵetu la ĵurnalon kaj ekpensu

Here it is referring to the reader's own television set. If it was just *televido* they would be asking the reader to somehow switch off the television broadcast for everyone.

Answer (score 5):

"Televidilo" is the hardware to watch. "Televido" is the concept.

Comment: Just to clarify the etymology: _-il_ is the affix for an instrument. So a _televidilo_ is literally an instrument for _televido_, or generally a TV set.